# How can we define energy other than the definition that it's a capability to do work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, definition

It is actually a property of energy that it can do some work not an actual mean to define it because we cannot define a thing on the basis of what it is doing or what it can do.

Comment: Why can't you "define a thing on the basis of ..."?  Is that just your opinion or does it violate some law of linguistics, or logic?

Comment: yes sir, i know it can do some work but will we be  able to understand energy by saying that it is just a capability to do work.if i say to define yourself, so by just saying what you are doing or what you can do will you be defined appropriately.

Comment: You are making this up.  You cannot redefine the way words are defined to create an issue.

Comment: Energy cannot be a property of an object.  It is a description of the relationship an object has w/r to the other objects around it.  Since K.E. depends on a reference frame, all objects at rest relative to a given object would measure no K.E. and the object in question cannot affect any other the other via direct contact.  Energy is a measure of an equivalence relation, not a property.

Comment: we  can redefine.

Comment: to make it more appropriate or to make wrong into right

Comment: I think this is just a really inappropriate question and a red herring.  I'm voting to close it.  You cannot tacitly redefine things just because.  These definitions are based on observation and fact, not opinion and wishful thinking.

Comment: as you wish sir

Answer (score 1):

To set up a mathematical model that describes a physical system, one has to define observables, and one has to define "laws", i.e. axioms imposed on the mathematical model so that there is a correspondence of the mathematical solutions to the measured data and also predictions for future behavior.

Here we start with the [definition of a force](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/force.html#defor) in words:

> One of the foundation concepts of physics, a force may be thought of as any influence which tends to change the motion of an object.

"Foundation" means it is a definition, expressed differently in different physics models

[image: force]

This leads sequentially to  to the concepts of ["work" "energy" "power"](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/work.html)

> work:refers to an activity involving a force and movement in the directon of the force. A force of 20 newtons pushing an object 5 meters in the direction of the force does 100 joules of work.
>
> energy:is the capacity for doing work. You must have energy to accomplish work - it is like the "currency" for performing work. To do 100 joules of work, you must expend 100 joules of energy.

So in the manner that the physics models have developed, there is no other definition.

Can one invent another definition? Yes, Example :One may start postulating the Lorenz transformations on four vectors  and postulate that "energy is the value in the four vector that gives as the length the invariant mass of the particle given the momentum". Momentum, mv, is the basis in this case. This would be correct, but a very complicated way of defining energy, particularly energy in the emergent classical mechanics system.

Answer (score 1):

"[…] we cannot define a thing on the basis of what it is doing or what it can do."

Why not? Try defining *a progressive wave* other than in terms of what it's doing!

In my opinion "The energy of a system is the amount of work it can do" is an excellent *starting* definition of energy. It enables one to derive the Newtonian formula ($\frac{1}{2}mv^2$) for kinetic energy, and formulae for potential energy in uniform and inverse square law fields, escape velocities, closest distances of approach and so on.

Later on one discovers various difficulties with the "amount of work it can do" definition. The Second law of Thermodynamics is, on the face of it, a glaring example. If heat is a form of energy, but you can't turn it all into work, that seems to generate a contradiction. [This argument is (deliberately) rather sloppily stated.] Another example: according to quantum mechanics an oscillatory system (e.g. a diatomic molecule) has a *zero point energy*, that is a minimum energy that cannot be removed from the system, so the system's energy is greater than the amount of work it can do!

There are ways of getting round these difficulties and preserving the "amount of work" definition of energy, but they come at the cost of caveats and interpretative devices (arguably sophistry) that spoil the original simplicity of the idea. In fact one may wish to abandon "the amount of work it can do" as a definition of energy, and to look upon energy as a conserved quantity which can be calculated for various systems by specific formulae or equations. An admission of defeat?

Comment: I think you CAN define something based on what it can do.  You point our the opinion based flaw in the OP, +1.  I think this should have been closed as opinion bases.

Comment: But even without the op's non-standard view on definitions in general, the question of how to define $energy$ is an interesting one.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, it is just a number associated with a system or object. For instance, a 2 kg ball moving with velocity 5 m/s has kinetic energy of 25 J. This number is always conserved for a system of objects (for instance 2 balls colliding, or two charges acting on each other) provided that no external forces act on it.

Comment: but we cannot define as just a no. associted with the object or system.

Comment: the upper answer is not quiet acceptable sir please tell something appropriate

Comment: Different types of energy have different "definitions". For instance, the kinetic energy of a moving body is defined by 1/2mv^2, potential energy is defined by mgh with respect to some point. However, for a closed system, the numerical sum of all these different energies is constant at any point in time no matter how the system changes.

Comment: @Akshaykumar, "not quite acceptable", "tell me something appropriate".  You question is not appropriate.  What is your agenda?

Comment: I donot want definition of different types of energy. I just need definition of term energy.

Comment: other than it is a capability of doing work.